# Invisible recaptcha in Expo SDK 37

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, react-native, expo

```js
const phoneProvider = new firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider();
            const verificationId = await phoneProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(
              phoneNumber,
              recaptchaVerifier.current
            );
            setVerificationId(verificationId);
```

Can we use without recaptchaVerifier.current

Answer (score 1):

No, recaptcha will always be required if you want to use the Firebase Phone Auth.

As it says in the documentation :

> Firebase phone authentication is not possible out of the box using the Firebase JS SDK. This because an Application Verifier object (reCAPTCHA) is needed as an additional security measure to verify that the user is real and not a bot.

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/firebase-recaptcha/